# How to check if a column in pandas dataframe has a value greater than mentioned value . If The column has values as lists

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hi I am trying to query an If condition on a column in pandas. 
The column has values as lists. But it throws error.

**Input:**

```
Name    Matches
John    [1, 0, 500,], [2, 0, 600,],[70,67,78]
Wall    [4, 0, 14], [2, 0, 40]
Austin  [1, 0, 5,], [0,2, 7,]
```

Expected Output:

```
Name    Matches                                 any_value_greater_than_10?
John    [1, 0, 500,], [2, 0, 600,],[70,67,78]   yes
Wall    [4, 0, 14], [2, 0, 40]                  yes
Austin  [1, 0, 5,], [0,2, 7,]                   no
```

Code:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('one.txt',sep = '\t')
df1['Matches'] =  df1['Matches'].astype(int)
df1['any_value_greater_than_10?'] = df1['Matches'].apply(lambda a: a > 10 in a)
print(df1)
```

Error:

```
invalid literal for int() with base 10: '[1, 0, 500,], [2, 0, 600,],[70,67,78]'
```

Is there any way in which i can find if the column 'Matches' has any value greater than 10 ? And return 'yes' if found so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `series.str.findall` and find all ints then compare:

```
['yes' if any(int(a)>10 for a in i) else 'no' for i in df['Matches'].str.findall('\d+')]
```

---

Example:

```
df['any_value_greater_than_10?'] = (['yes' if any(int(a)>10 for a in i) else 'no' 
                                       for i in df['Matches'].str.findall('\d+')])
print(df)
```

---

```
     Name                                Matches any_value_greater_than_10?
0    John  [1, 0, 500,], [2, 0, 600,],[70,67,78]                        yes
1    Wall                 [4, 0, 14], [2, 0, 40]                        yes
2  Austin                  [1, 0, 5,], [0,2, 7,]                         no
```

Comment: 'a' is variable for integer and 'i' is for one list ?  Example i = [1,0,500,] and a in 'i' would be 1  and 0 and 500 ?

Comment: @Anonymus yes exactly, a is an element inside the list i

Comment: I am getting error ''float' object is not iterable'. 
If i convert the column 'matches' into int, then list data will get disturbed. 
I tried replacing 'i' with '[i]'. But that gave another error. How do we iterate over float ?

Comment: @Anonymus you cant iterate over a float, did your data change? its best to ask a new question as this answered the original question

Comment: so the error was in rows where column 'matches' was blank. works fine after replace blank with 0